# missing keyword parameter is clearly included in api call

Tags: amadeus

I'm trying to set up a basic API call to Amadeus. All the correct parameters are included and I'm grabbing a fresh token for each call.

It's a React/Flask application.

Here's my endpoint in app/routes.py:

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin(origin='*')
def get_flights():

    api_key = os.environ.get('amadeus_api_key', None)
    api_secret = os.environ.get('amadeus_api_secret', None)

    # first, you must get an access token using your Amadeus credentials
    token_request = requests.post(
        'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token',
        data = {
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'client_id': api_key,
            'client_secret': api_secret
        }
    )
    token = token_request.json()['access_token']
    bearer = 'Bearer {}'.format(token)

    locations = requests.get(
        'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations',
        headers = {
            'Authorization': bearer 
        },
        data = {
            'subType': 'AIRPORT',
            'keyword': 'BOS'
        }
    )
    print(locations.json())

    # example:
    # https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations
    # ?subType=AIRPORT&keyword=BOS

    return jsonify({'token': token})
```

Here's the error:

```
{'errors': [{'status': 400, 'code': 32171, 'title': 'MANDATORY DATA MISSING', 'detail': 'Missing mandatory query parameter', 'source': {'parameter': 'keyword'}}]}
```

As you can see in the /search endpoint, the keyword parameter is clearly included.

What gives? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request to get the locations is not correctly built as it is sending `subType` and `keyword` as body instead of query parameters. According to `requests` documentation, you need to use `params`:

```
    locations = requests.get(
    'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations',
    headers = {
        'Authorization': bearer 
    },
    params = {
        'subType': 'AIRPORT',
        'keyword': 'BOS'
    }
)
```